# OSGi Security with Apache Karaf: no service ConditionalPermissionAdmin found

Tags: java, security, osgi, apache-karaf

I am trying to use [conditional permissions](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r5/core/org/osgi/service/condpermadmin/ConditionalPermissionAdmin.html) in my application, running in Karaf. The code is an excerpt from the book OSGi in Action (see the [full policy example](https://code.google.com/p/osgi-in-action/source/browse/trunk/chapter14/combined-example/org.foo.policy/src/org/foo/policy/Activator.java)) and boils down to:

```
ConditionalPermissionAdmin permAdmin = getConditionalPermissionAdmin(context);
ConditionalPermissionUpdate update = permAdmin.newConditionalPermissionUpdate();
List infos = update.getConditionalPermissionInfos();
infos.clear();

infos.add(permAdmin.newConditionalPermissionInfo(
        "All permissions",
        new ConditionInfo[]{
            new ConditionInfo(
            BundleLocationCondition.class.getName(),
            new String[]{FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getLocation()})
        },
        new PermissionInfo[]{
            new PermissionInfo(AllPermission.class.getName(), "*", "*")
        },
        ConditionalPermissionInfo.ALLOW));
update.commit();
```

However, **no ConditionalPermissionAdmin service seems to be registered by Karaf**, as I get a `null` ServiceReference when looking for it.

Is there a problem with the Karaf security layer? How do I activate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's nothing wrong with Karaf, as you most likely are using Karaf out of the Box you most likely are also using the Felix Framework. For Felix you'll need to deploy the extra org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.security/1.4.0/ org.apache.felix.framework.security-1.4.0.jar=1. (most likely a newer version is also needed ;-) )
Equinox comes with this already enabled. 
See more at [my blog](http://notizblog.nierbeck.de/2010/10/blocking-systemexit-in-osgi-part-iv/)

Comment: Well guessed: I'm using Felix under the hood. I added `mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.framework.security` to my existing features, works like a charm!
I'm getting a ClassNotFound exception `PermissionAdmin not found by org.apache.aries.jmx.core` when I start it though. Any idea where this could come from?

Comment: I wonder if a refresh of the aries core bundle already solves this, if so make sure you have the permissionsadmin bundle in the startup.properties configured at an early stage (low startlevel).